# How are the *constant vectors* different from *vector fields* in terms of their respective transfomation properties?

Tags: differential-geometry, vectors, tensor-calculus, vector-fields, covariance

How does one distinguish between the transformation properties of a scalar field $\phi(\textbf{r})$ or vector field $\textbf{A}(\textbf{r})$ (more generally, the tensor fields) from the transformation of ordinary scalars or vectors (which are not fields in the sense that they are not defined as the function of space)?

**EDIT:** For simplicity, I want to understand the transformation rule of  constant vector and and vector field under rotation. Under rotations, the components of a constant vector $\textbf{A}$ transforms as: $$A^\prime_i=R_{ij}A_j$$ Does the same rule apply for vector fields too? Will it not matter that the argument of $\textbf{A}(\textbf{r})$ also transforms under rotation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it does affect the argument as well. The full transformation rule is given by:
$$ \mathbf{A}(\mathbf{x}) \rightarrow R\mathbf{A}(R^{-1}\mathbf{x}) , $$
where $\mathbf{A}(\mathbf{x})$ is the vector field as a fucntion of the position vector $\mathbf{x}$ and $R$ is the rotation matrix.